# Sox, mixing mono inputs into mono output (efficiently)

Tags: noise

I want to mix two mono files, signal.wav and noise.wav, into a single mono file, signal_noise_mono.wav.

Currently, I know how to mix the two input files into a stereo file and then remix it to mono, but I would like to mix down to mono directly, and avoid the intermediate file.

```
# Merge signal (mono, L) and noise (mono, R) into a stereo file
sox -M signal.wav noise.wav signal_noise_stereo.wav

# Remix channels 1 & 2 from the stereo file into a single mono file
sox signal_noise_stereo.wav signal_noise_mono.wav remix 1,2
```

Any tips? Have I missed an obvious sox switch?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's but a `sox` usage, not a DSP question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, I figured dsp.se folks may face this issue in the future, or know how to solve it (see answer below). Where do you suggest I ask this instead?

Comment: Try superuser.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you want to add two signals, together?
I guess that you are missing `-m` switch.

Generate two test files (sweep and sine):

```
sox -Dr 16000 -c 1 -b 16 -n sine.wav synth 5 sin 1000
sox -Dr 16000 -c 1 -b 16 -n sweep.wav synth 10 sine 100:8000
```

Merge them together:

```
sox -m sweep.wav sine.wav -Dr 16000 out.wav
```

Using `soxi out.wav` you can see that produced file is mono:

```
Input File     : 'out.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 16000
Precision      : 16-bit
Duration       : 00:00:10.00 = 160000 samples ~ 750 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 320k
Bit Rate       : 256k
Sample Encoding: 16-bit Signed Integer PCM
```

Now you can observe the spectrograms:

```
sox sine.wav -n spectrogram -o sine.png
sox sweep.wav -n spectrogram -o sweep.png
sox out.wav -n spectrogram -o out.png
```

Sine:

[image]

Sweep:

[image]

Merged together:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, I need -m (mix), not -M (merge). Thanks! The documentation is not very clear about the difference between these...